# Userdefined margins in WPF printing

Tags: .net, wpf, printing, margin

Most printing samples for WPF go like this:

```
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
           StackPanel myPanel = new StackPanel();
           myPanel.Margin = new Thickness(15);
           Image myImage = new Image();
           myImage.Width = dialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
           myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
           myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/picture.bmp"));
           myPanel.Children.Add(myImage);
           myPanel.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
           myPanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), myPanel.DesiredSize));
           dialog.PrintVisual(myPanel, "A Great Image.");
        }
```

What I don't like about this is, that they always set the margin to a fixed value.
But in PrintDialog the user has the option to choose a individual margin that no sample cares about. If the user now selects a margin that is larger as the fixed margin set by program, the printout is truncated.
Is there a way to get the user selected margin value from PrintDialog?

TIA
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure that the margin that you are changing in the `PrintDialog` is a printer driver-specific setting. It's normal that you cannot access the setting from .NET.

Comment: I found a solution:
            PrintDocumentImageableArea area = null;
            XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref area);

The margins are in the area object.
But this always opens the print dialog, maybe I find some way to get the default margins without opening the dialog.